# Type some text with xdotool independently of the keyboard layout

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xdotool

The command

```
xdotool type "hello"
```

can be used to type the word *hello*. But only if the keyboard layout is not English, otherwise it will type something else.

How can I solve this problem so that `xdotool` will always type hello in any layout.

I use the latest `xdotool` in Ubuntu 14.04 repo.

Comment: It should work. Changing the keyboard layout doesn't change the result here. Maybe you are running into [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/semicomplete/issues/detail?id=13) that occured when having multiple layouts configured, and was [fixed here](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/commit/bbf0e70ab614852cff8111cabeed8d5ffa9554e0) ?

Comment: Should I recompile that code and use that xdotool instead of the latest in repo?

Comment: Yes, you can try the latest git version and see if it still happens. Here `xdotool -v` says I'm using version  2.20110530.1.

Comment: I have version 3.20140217.1

Comment: If it still doesn't work, add to your question how your are using xdotool exactly, how you call it, on which application you are trying to type (maybe the application interprets keycodes with its own keymap for instance).

Comment: There's no other details. I have latest xdotool in Ubuntu 14.04. I open a terminal and try to run `xdotool type "hello"`. It types hello only if the keyboard layout is set to English. Otherwise it will type as if I'm typing hello in the other layout. But I want xdotool to type always in English layout.

Answer (score 3):

xdotool seems to have a bug, If you are not using the `us` keyboard layout, and your keyboard layout was set through an Xorg configuration file (not `setxkbmap`), it will use the corresponding keysyms from the `us` layout.

To work around this, simply set your keyboard layout (again) in your `.xinitrc` file, or run `setxkbmap yourlayout` before using xdotool.

Comment: this works beatifully, unfortunately the command takes ~0.5 sec which is not feasible.